# Correct design of Repository->Service->Controller?

Tags: .net, architecture, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern

I'm wondering if I'm using the correct architecture in my application.

After calling an endpoint in my API, I'm currently going through the following flow:
`Api.EmployeeController.Update(Api.EmployeeUpdateDto)` => `Services.EmployeeService.Update(Service.EmployeeUpdateDto)` => `Data.EmployeeRepository.Update(Entities.Employee)` => `Data.EfDbContext.Employees.Update(Entities.Employee)`

To explain a but more, my API endpoint take `Api.EmployeeUpdateDto`, within the controller it's being mapped to `Services.EmployeeUpdateDto` and passed to `Services.EmployeeService.Update()`.
Within `Services.EmployeeService.Update()` it retrieves the actual db entity by Id and updates it's values, afterwards it's passed to `EmployeeRepository.Update()` which in turn calls the underlying EF db context.

For some reason my gut tells me that it's complicated with too many layers, am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are complicating things, but it's a bit subtle.  The trick is your layer between the Repository & your service layer should be passing in the EmployeeUpdateDTO, and shouldn't know anything about the entity.  The entity should be contained inside your Repository layer.

I'm not quite sure why you have an EmployeeUpdateDTO and not just an EmployeeDTO though, I'd just simplify that to EmployeeDTO, at which point you have an actual domain object.

This does mean your service-layer is really thin, which, for a straight CRUD operation is normal.  Unless you are doing things like decorating the EmployeeDTO with logic like update date and such it's pretty much boiler-plate passthrough.

Api.EmployeeController.Update(Api.EmployeeUpdateDto) => Services.EmployeeService.Update(Service.EmployeeDto) => Data.EmployeeRepository.Update(Service.EmployeeDto) => Data.EfDbContext.Employees.Update(Entities.Employee)

Comment: Just wanted to add here that `*Dto` is either a bad name for a domain object or it is none. Since the domain is the core of your application, the domain object should be `Employee`. Representations for UI should be named *Dto (since most of the time they are actually transfered over the wire). If you have another object for persistence, thats fine but reserve the Business name (Employee) for the domain layer

Answer (score 0):

Ok. These where the steps:

1. Api.EmployeeController.Update(Api.EmployeeUpdateDto)
2. Services.EmployeeService.Update(Service.EmployeeUpdateDto)
3. Data.EmployeeRepository.Update(Entities.Employee)
4. Data.EfDbContext.Employees.Update(Entities.Employee)

First of all. It's great that you have a `EmployeeUpdateDto` since your typically do not update exactly the same fields as when creating a new entity. I do however usually do a more task based approach like `LockUserDTO`, `RenameUserDTO` etc,

There are two types of services in DDD. Application services and domain services. Application services acts as a facade to protect your domain while domain services are used to coordinate work between multiple entities.

`Service.EmployeeUpdateDto` doesn't really add any value. If the API dto changes, or if the entity changes it still need to get updated. So it doesn't provide any further abstraction contra just having the API dto. Therefore I would remove it and let the application service use the API dto directly.

1. Api.EmployeeController.Update(Api.EmployeeUpdateDto)
2. Services.EmployeeService.Update(Api.EmployeeUpdateDto)
3. Data.EmployeeRepository.Update(Entities.Employee)
4. Data.EfDbContext.Employees.Update(Entities.Employee)

I'm typically avoid using the domain entity as a DB entity since it often requires compromises in the design so that the ORM can persist it properly. Remember, the domain entities are your most precious treasure. The only thing that should drive their design is the domain.